# How to set width and positon ModalDialog in the center before it loads?

Tags: ios, objective-c, modal-dialog

I created a modal dialog in my viewController.

```
dialogViewController *dialog = [[dialogViewController alloc] init];

dialog.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
dialog.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
dialog.indexPath = indexPath;
dialog.campaignArray = self.campaignArray;

dialog.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(dialog.view.superview.frame.origin.x+250, dialog.view.superview.frame.origin.y, dialog.view.superview.frame.size.width-250, dialog.view.superview.frame.size.height);

[self presentViewController:dialog animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The above changes the width but not the x position of the modal dialog. It works in the modalDialog but then user can see it being resized.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use

```
UIModalPresentationFormSheet
```

the controller will be centred. There is very specific formatting included in this. If you want anything different, you will have to build your own.

> The width and height of the presented view are smaller than those of the screen and the view is centered onscreen. If the device is in a landscape orientation and the keyboard is visible, the position of the view is adjusted upward so the view remains visible. All uncovered areas are dimmed to prevent the user from interacting with them.

Comment: Its strange that I can change the x and y positions after it loads but not before. While width and height can change at anytime. If I change width then its not in the centre.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dialogViewController *dialog = [[dialogViewController alloc] init];

dialog.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
dialog.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
dialog.indexPath = indexPath;
dialog.campaignArray = self.campaignArray;

[self presentViewController:dialog animated:YES completion:nil];

CGRect dlgFrame  = dialog.view.superview.frame;
dlgFrame.size.width -= 250.0;
dialog.view.superview.frame = dlgFrame;
```

Comment: It changes the width but then the dialog is not in the middle. I tried this dlgFrame.origin.x += 250.0; but it did nothing.

Comment: How about adding this line after changing the width: dialog.view.superview.center = self.view.center;